# Problem Measuring Current in a High Voltage circuit with arduino

Tags: arduino, amplifier, current-measurement

I 'm measuring a current in a resistor as shown in the picture below. There I'm using a voltage substractor with an LM324 Operational Amplifier. I'm having trouble in the real World when the voltage is grater than 12 V , the amplifier behaves strangely (I'm feeding the amplifier with 12 V ).

What can I do in order to properly measure this current with  such a high voltage in the nodes of the resistor. I need to get to 60 V. I'm planning to send this voltage signal to Arduino, so I need it to be beteween 0-5V .

Any Help is appreciated.

[image: Problem's circuit]

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using the circuit you are using now, consider the [LTC4151](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/4151ff.pdf).  It works with input voltages up to 80V.

[image]

Instead of a voltage output, it uses an I2C interface, which should be available on the Arduino.

It is available for $5.55 [from Digi-Key](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/LTC4151CMS-1%23PBF/LTC4151CMS-1%23PBF-ND/1814467).

Comment: Are there any other solutions ?. Where I live I can't get that component. What do you think of this current sensor http://www.sigmaelectronica.net/manuals/ACS714.pdf

Comment: @Keith The ACS714 looks like an excellent find.  You didn't mention how much current you will be measuring, but since the ACS714ELCTR-05B-T outputs 185 mV/A, if you were to measure 100 mA, it would output only 18.5 mV.  A 10-bit ADC with a 5v reference only has a resolution of about 5 mV per bit. So you might want to stick a op amp between the output of the ACS714 and your ADC.

Comment: I'm going to be measuring a current between 0-20 mA.  So I think I will need an op-amp with a high gain. Or what else can I do ?

Comment: @Keith Correct, you need a high gain.  Since the current should change rather slowly (I assume), you can get away with using a single op amp in a non-inverting configuration.   For an ADC with a 3.3V range, you could use a gain of 800 (185*.02*800 = 2.96V).  For an ADC with a range of 5V, you could use a gain of 1200 (185*.02*1200=4.44V).

Comment: I believe there are a lot of op-amps where I live, Which one do you recommend me to amplify with such a High gain ?

Comment: @Keith I'm mostly a digital, not analog type, but I think at close to DC you can get by with most anything, such as the LM324 which is very common.